# Using SQL, is it possible to create global temporary table with same format level identifier as original file(PF) it is based on?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

Program A calls program B.
I am creating the global temporary table based on File A in Prog B.

I have to open and read the temporary table in Program A. I have used EXTFILE opcode in F Spec to compile the Prog A.

```
fFILEA   if   e             disk    extfile(wrk_filnam)
f                                      usropn

/free

wrk_filnam = 'QTEMP/TEMP_TABLE'

open FILEA

/end-free
```

When i return to Prog A and Open File A , I am getting level check error as temporary table is created with new format level identifier.

Is there a workaround ? If i can do with CRTDUPOBJ then it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sql statement `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable LIKE srctable RCDFMT srcfmt` will create `tmptable` with the same format level identifier as `srctable` as long as you make sure that `srcfmt` is the same record format name as the original.

Are you compiling with the correct file to get the correct level identifier?  You can use `DSPPGMREF` to find out the level identifier expected by the program for each file.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I was getting different identifier because of the record format i believe.

Answer (score 1):

CRTDUPOBJ should create a file with the same format level identifier as the original file.

Comment: Yes I can. I didn't want to use CRTDUPOBJ. Thanks for you answer.